# How to make content within header slide with header

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, nav

Ideally, I'd like the content within the header to scroll up to just show the nav list and hide the logo when the user scrolls (so the header doesn't take up as much space on the screen when the user is viewing the website). Any idea what I'm doing wrong? As of now, the header background slides up but the content within the header stays in position. I'm assuming there's a simple solution to this that I'm missing, thanks.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="address">
        <ul>
            <li>Address</li>
            <li>info@email.com</li>
            <li>(999) 999 9999</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p id="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </p>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#slider">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#wwd">What</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hwdi">How</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutanchor">Who</a></li>
            <li><a href="#workanchor">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
height: 5000px;
}
#header {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#address {
    width: 100%;
    background: #95c73a;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
    #address ul {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #address li {
        float: left;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 15px;
        font-size: .5em;
        line-height: 18px;
        position: relative;
        right: 50%;
    }

    #address i {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    #address li:last-child i {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    #logo {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 50%;
        left: -345px;
        width: 690px;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    nav ul li a i {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        color: #333 !important;
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        color: #333;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 800;
        transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #95c73a;
    }
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
        $('#header').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $nav = $('#header');
        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                    height:'80px'
                }, 600);
            }
        } else {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                    height:'165px'
                }, 600);
            }  
        }
    });
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bnsUB/143/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       $(window).scroll(function(){
            var $nav = $('#header');
            if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                    $('#logo').fadeOut(300);
                    $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                        height:'80px'
                    }, 600);
                }
            } else {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                    $('#logo').fadeIn(300);
                    $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                        height:'165px'
                    }, 600);
                }  
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnsUB/146/

Comment: @user3089222 Please mark this answer as accepted it it resolved your question.  Otherwise give feeback, thanks.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. How to mark as resolved wasn't very intuitive, my mistake.